# Why cannot export a PureComponent

Tags: reactjs, components

I have it working :

```
export class FormAuto extends React.PureComponent {
   constructor(props) {
     ...
   }
  ....
}
```

I import the composent like this : `import { FormAuto } from './FormAuto'`

But I want to do it like this, to use `connect` from redux :

```
class FormAuto extends React.PureComponent {
   constructor(props) {
     ...
   }
  ....
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FormAuto);
```

But i have this error :

> Module ../../FormAuto has no exported member 'FormAuto'

If I import the composent like this : `import FormAuto from './FormAuto'`
the component is no longer displayed.

Can you help me ?

Comment: how are you importing the component

Comment: I think this is based on how you import the component, for the second import you should not wrap it in curly braces: import FormAuto from "your/path";

Comment: "component is no longer displayed" is there an error?

Comment: Depending on your map state to props you don't need pure component. If map state is like `mapStateToProps=state({prop:{new:reference}})` it'll create a new reference for prop every render and pure component will fail to see nothing has changed. If you want to get the best results you can look into reselect, that would prevent you from duplication logic as well, for example `mapStateToProps=state=>{a:state.a}` You may repeat the `state.a` in multiple map state functions. Or if you calculate values you may repeat them in map state functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't related to `PureComponent`. It is because you changed from a *named* export to a *default* export.

You have two options.

1. Use a default import

```js
import FormAuto from './path/to/FormAuto'
```

2. Do a named export:

```js
// Either the const or the class will need to be renamed in this scenario
export const FormAuto = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FormAuto);
```

The bottom line is you need to keep them consistent.

#### For reference:

**Default**

```js
export default MyComponent

// The import name can be anything you choose. 
// For clarity it may be preferred to use the component name
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
```

**Named**

```js
export MyComponent

import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
```

Comment: I have this on the export : [eslint] 'FormAuto' is already defined. (no-redeclare)

Comment: Ah you're right, my mistake. You will need to either rename the exported const, or the class. They can't share the same name.